# Python Flask routes conflict

Tags: flask

I am using python flask for a web application and I have following routes in my python file

```
@app.route("/admin", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def admin():
    print "In admin method. With request method: ", request.method
    pass

@app.route("/<query>", methods=['GET'])
def search(query):
    print "In search method. With request method: ", request.method
    pass
```

My app is doing something very weird. I added print statements to know where the request goes through and in my admin.html file when I submit the form that looks like below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.form-horizontal').submit(function() {
      console.log(JSON.stringify($(this)));
      var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
      $.post($(this).attr("action"), formData, function(data) {
        alert(data);
      });
      return false;
    });
  });
</script>

<form class="form-horizontal" action="/admin" method="post">
  <input id="query" type="file">
  <input id="query2" type="file">
  <button type="submit">Update Data</button>
</form>
```

Now, in my console I see log that looks like below

```
In admin method. Request method:  GET
In admin method. Request method:  POST
**In search method. With request method:  GET**
```

The bolded line is what makes me uncomfortable and looks suspicious to me. When I submit post request to my /admin, why is another GET request executed by flask app ?

Comment: where is the first GET in your console output coming from? There's an ambiguity in your routes where a GET request can be mapped to both '/admin' and the catch-all '/<query>'. I suspect the POST is not the problem, but any GET may trigger both routes (which is indeed very strange). I would also print query within the search function to see what is being sent to debug this. also show any arguments, data, form, etc. (request.args, request.form, request.data) to debug.

Comment: Is there a search method GET when you return a response from the admin method?

Comment: @GG_Python I renamed the path to "/admin/update" to get around this issue.

Comment: @Celeo:There is no search method call from admin method

Answer (score 0):

```
@app.route("/<query>", methods=['GET'])
```

this route is very wide and it grabs all **/admin** requests. Try to make for example routes **/admin/** and **/r/**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of use:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="/admin" method="post">
```

You can try this one:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="{{ url_for('admin') }}" method="post">
```